# Network errors only in chrome browser for selenium tests

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I am facing below stack of errors with my selenium tests which are passed yesterday. I am facing issue only when running tests in chrome browser. For rest of the browsers the tests are running perfect. i tried updating the chrome version to latest. And even updated selenium jars to latest versions.
Any fix with out changing the existing framework please?

I tried most of the fixes available in stackoverflow. Still no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Computer auto updated chrome browser at some point.

So I got the previous version chrome web driver.

I got rid of all the errors in the screenshot and able to run tests succesfully